# VueJS + TypeScript decorator issue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-cli

I have a strange issue just with creating a new app with the vue-cli : the HelloWorld component has an error with decorators.
I did not touch to anything, all the code and configuration comes from the vue-cli.

Here is the error:

```
ERROR in /Users/JohnSmith/test/src/components/HelloWorld.vue
37:1 Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
  Type '<VC extends VueClass<Vue>>(target: VC) => VC' is missing the following properties from type 'typeof HelloWorld': extend, nextTick, set, delete, and 7 more.
    35 | import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
    36 | 
  > 37 | @Component
       | ^
    38 | export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
    39 |   @Prop() private msg!: string;
    40 | }
```

I have found this workaround:

```
@Component({
  props: {
    msg: {type: String},
  },
})
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  // @Prop() private msg!: string;
}
```

But I would like to use the decorators, and this is not normal to have errors with the generated dummy project.

This is my environment:

- macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
- node v11.3.0 (with brew)
- npm 6.4.1
- yarn 1.12.3 (with brew)
- Vue CLI v3.2.1
- brew doctor is fine

And here are the vue-cli options I used for creating the project:

```
? Please pick a preset: Manually select features
? Check the features needed for your project: Babel, TS, PWA, Router, Vuex, CSS Pre-processors, Linter
? Use class-style component syntax? Yes
? Use Babel alongside TypeScript for auto-detected polyfills? Yes
? Use history mode for router? (Requires proper server setup for index fallback in production) Yes
? Pick a CSS pre-processor (PostCSS, Autoprefixer and CSS Modules are supported by default): Sass/SCSS
? Pick a linter / formatter config: TSLint
? Pick additional lint features: (Press <space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection)Lint on save
? Where do you prefer placing config for Babel, PostCSS, ESLint, etc.? In dedicated config files
? Save this as a preset for future projects? No
```

I did not find any info about this issue anywhere.

Were does it come from ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here is the issue about this on github: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/294. It is already fixed and will be released soon and there is also a workaround for this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/294#issuecomment-445725337

Comment: @nemesv Ok, I've missed that ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Try to import Vue from vue ... 
like:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
@Component
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  @Prop() private msg!: string;
}
```